# Recommender system for related answers

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal

When reading an answer for a question it is hard to know whether there is information elsewhere in stack overflow which is relevant to that specific answer (not question).

I would like an option where when I upvote an answer I would get recommendations for similar answers, one way to do this is see the links which people post in their answer. find answers which share the same links and open a scrollable box under the answer when upvoting.

This can serve 3 purposes:

- easily finding specific answers (not questions) which relate to the ones you like - better navigation in SO
- better suggestion system than trying to find similarity in the entire question - more relevant to the reader
- encouraging upvotes on good answers - since I will get a list of similar answers on the subject, I'm more inclined to upvote sort of like a "micro-reward"

EDIT: I'll add a simple example

Say I read a question about CSS which was answered by several people like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854748/why-is-it-necessary-a-css-file-when-we-can-declare-the-styles-in-the-html-code). I thought JohnP's answer was great but I also was interested in @Damien's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854748/why-is-it-necessary-a-css-file-when-we-can-declare-the-styles-in-the-html-code/5854805#5854805) I thought the wiki link was informative and I'm interested in the subject he discussed. Now, since the answer is only one of many and the main topic is CSS usage I don't get recommendations for questions/answers on the @Damiens answer. so I can search SO again for the subject discussed and try and find relevant answers which deal with the subject, in this case: Using CSS for separation of presentation and content.

What I think would be ideal is that when upvoting @Damien's answer a box would open (similar to question writing) just under the question and a suggestion for a more relevant (question/answer) would be suggested such as @Andrew's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260391/what-is-the-actual-meaning-of-seperation-of-content-and-presentation/2260422#2260422) to the usage of separation of presentation and content with examples of CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree. The navigation you'd expect would be Problem => Solution. Wouldn't most users approach the site from the other side? They have a problem and they need a  solution for it.

It could be argued that when you're recommending similar answers, you're actually recommending similar problems since the answer applies to them as well.

Comment: yes, but it doesn't have to be (and often is not) a one to one mapping, i.e.: problem -> 1 solution. it often is: problem -> N solutions. in this case getting to a list of possible answers is a good thing. otherwise you could make the case for deleting all other answers once an answer has been accepted

Comment: @asaf I didn't say it's 1 to 1. What I mean is that, this wouldn't improve things much because when you're getting similar solutions you're actually getting a list of similar questions since that's the primary organization of the site.